# execute action in PLY Python before the symbol are parsed

Tags: python, yacc, ply

I'm making a parser to parse tokens immediately into Three Address Code.
To generate the correct TAC code when calling a function I need to call my function "GiveTac" before and after all the tokens are parsed.

My problem is I can't find a way to call a function before the parses a token.  In the documentation of PLY there is a section 6.11 embedded actions that claims you can simply add an empty rule like this:

```
def p_foo(p):
    "foo : A seen_A B C D"
    print("Parsed a foo", p[1],p[3],p[4],p[5])
    print("seen_A returned", p[2])

def p_seen_A(p):
    "seen_A :"
    print("Saw an A = ", p[-1])   # Access grammar symbol to left
    p[0] = some_value            # Assign value to seen_A
```

but if I try this in my code I always get an "Syntax error in input!" error.
This is my code:

```
def p_fun_declaration_type_formal_pars_block(p):
    'fun_declaration    : before type NAME LPAR formal_pars RPAR block'


def p_fun_before_fun(p):
    'before :'
    GiveTAC("function",None,None,'main')
    p[0]=p[1]
```

If I remove the "before" in my p_fun_declaration_type_formal_pars_block function it does accept my syntax.

Pastebin links of my code:
[Yacc.py](http://pastebin.com/S5nFkQEn)

[Parser.out](http://pastebin.com/93Jyac82)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with either ply 3.4 or ply 3.6. Both accept the syntax fine, as long as there is a space before the colon. Your usage of `p[1]` in `p_fun_before_fun` will throw an IndexError, though.

Comment: I added my code in the description of my problem. The moment I remove the before line in my code everything seems to work. I noticed it fails the moment I have other empty rules in my grammar for example my "p_var_declarations_empty(p)" function. I don't understand why those empty rules make my syntax to fail.

Comment: does ply report a reduce/reduce conflict?

Comment: PLY only reports shift/reduce problems after adding the before in my function. I added in my problem description my parser.out file.

WARNING: 
WARNING: Conflicts:
WARNING: 
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for INT in state 0 resolved as shift
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for CHAR in state 0 resolved as shift
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for INT in state 7 resolved as shift
WARNING: shift/reduce conflict for CHAR in state 7 resolved as shift